# Converting a field set into javascript variable

Tags: php, javascript, fieldset

I have some values in a PHP variable that is the address of customer. It is passed into the fieldset in html to show on the page.

```
<fieldset>
            <address><?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress()->getFormated(true) ?></address>
</fieldset>
```

I want to get each value in the set into a javascript variable. How can I do that?

```
<?php $_ad = $_order->getShippingAddress()->getFormated(true);?>
```

I want the values from $_ad into the javascript variable. I have tried to do so but i can only get one index like $_ad[0]. that gives only one alphabet!!!

Here is what I have tried,

```
val =  '<?php echo $_ad[0] ;?>';
```

Comment: <address> is not a valid html tag

Comment: I'm not interested in that!!!

Comment: @JvdBerg [it is in html5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-address-element.html#the-address-element)

Comment: <?php $_ad = $_order->getShippingAddress()->getFormated(true);?>

Comment: I want to get the values from this variable into a javascript varible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since javascript is evaluated on the client side and php on the server side, there is no direct way to interact or exchange variables.

You can either expose a webservice that you can then access from javascript via an ajax call. Or you could just parse the data from the page, since you know for sure, that there will be a fieldset with a address inside it. Use jQuery and try something like this:

```
var addresses = $("address").map(function() { return [this.innerHTML.split("<br>")]; });
```

[jsFiddle for that](http://jsfiddle.net/PMTCp/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get it from the rendered HTML with

```
var addresses = document.getElementsByTagName('address'),
    addresslist = [];
for(var i = 0, len = addresses.length;i<len;i++){
    addresslist.push( addresses[i].innerHTML );
}
```

Comment: where is len declaration? - of course replace len < address.length with  len = address.length

Comment: @LukeAdamczewski, thanks for the heads up ... mistyped `<` instead of `=`

Comment: Ok I received the data. But i want to get it individually!

Comment: what i received is, mjq<br> city<br> country<br>

Answer (score 1):

With [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
var addresses = [];

$('address').each(function(){
    addresses.push($(this).text());
});
```

[Try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/PMTCp/).

Comment: you can actually map the result of your query instead of constructing a new array in the loop yourself. I prefer it because it is more expressive and fits on one line :)